# awk array to print line before the first match

Tags: bash, awk, grep, head

For a block of text:

```
        USB2.1 Hub:

          Product ID: 0x0610

            Dell Universal Dock D6000:

              Product ID: 0x6006
              Vendor ID: 0x17e9  (DisplayLink (UK) Ltd.)
              Version: 31.27
              Serial Number: 1810132665
              Speed: Up to 5 Gb/s
              Manufacturer: DisplayLink
```

..on detecting the string `DisplayLink` (I've been using `Manufacturer` but in theory either should work) I'd like to return `Dell Universal Dock D6000` (or specifically, the entire line between the two lines containing `Product ID`).

This should be doable with some `awk` array:

`awk '/DisplayLink/ { for(i=NR-8;i<NR;i++) if(i>0) print a[i]; print; exit} {a[NR}=$0}'` returned a syntax error.

Using this (admittedly ugly, inefficient) chain of tools returns the desired result:
`grep "Manufacturer: DisplayLink" -B7 -n | head -1 | awk -F'[ :]+' '{ $1=""; print $0 }'`

Comment: Can you edit your original post to add expected output?

Comment: please confirm *which* `DisplayLink` you're trying to match (there are 2 in the sample)

Comment: the syntax error (which you should show in the question) relates to this typo ... `a[NR}=$0` ... you've used a brace (`}`) instead of a square bracket (`]`) to close the array index reference; correct syntax would be `a[NR]=$0`

Comment: If you tweak your answer you get (what I believe to be) your desired outcome: `awk '/Man.*DisplayLink/ {print a[(NR - 7)]; print; exit} {a[NR]=$0}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions:

- we want to match on `Manufacturer: DisplayLink`
- we want to exit the script as soon as we find the match (ie, if there are multiple matches then we'll only show the first match)

Tweaking OP's current code (store all lines in memory, then print line # `NR-7`):

```
awk '
/Manufacturer: DisplayLink/ { i=NR-7; if (i>0) print a[i]; exit} 
                            { a[NR]=$0 }
' dell.dat
```

An alternative to OP's code that stores just the last 7 lines (via a modulo 7 index):

```
awk '
/Manufacturer: DisplayLink/ { i=NR-7; if (i>0) print a[i%7]; exit }
                            { a[NR%7] = $0 }
' dell.dat
```

Yet another alternative approach requiring two reads of the input file; first read notes the line where we find the match and then subtracts 7 (call this `line_no`); the second read then prints the line where `FNR == line_no`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /Manufacturer: DisplayLink/ { line_no = FNR-7; nextfile } 
     FNR==line_no
' dell.dat dell.dat
```

All of these generate:

```
            Dell Universal Dock D6000:
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the differences between these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is to use the tac command to display the file on the screen in reverse from the last line to the first line, so that it can be processed normally using conventional methods (people who hope to understand can provide additional explanations)

```
tac file |awk '/Manufacturer: DisplayLink/{a=8}{if(--a==0)print}'
```

The second method is to use the grep method to compress the file into one line for processing. \N is to match non line breaks, \n is to match line breaks, and according to the meaning of the question, regular matching is sufficient

```
grep -Poz '\N+\n(?=(\N*\n){6}\s+Manufacturer)' file
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**